# Appointment booking workflow in FHIR

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir, hl7-fhir

I am trying to understand what is the appointment booking workflow in FHIR ?
Will I be first querying Schedule resource and then Slot resource ?
Is such workflow mentioned anywhere in FHIR documentation and shall I expect my clients to follow it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a brief summary of the scheduling workflow on the appointment page.
http://hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html#5.27.1.1

You should also then review the tables that describe some of the common status transitions which gives some guidance on the relationship/meaning between each of the resources.
http://hl7.org/fhir/appointment.html#typical

We are also trying to get more complete guidance/worked examples that you can refer to for this purpose, but that is not ready/available at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the response, where can I get exact info/http request along with parameters to book appointment on a particular slot ?